# PHP or Nginx configuration settings in AWS Auto-Scaling group

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, nfs, autoscaling

I did all the changes to AWS EC2 machine for Nginx & settings up PHP values and tested everything and than baked the AMI so it can be launched under AWS auto-scaling group.

All is good, but when developers or application rewrite requires sometimes to make change in PHP values or doing some new rewriting rules in nginx conf file, I always have to re-bake the whole AMI after each time disturbing my complete auto-scaling infrastructure and making server down.

I must be wrong! what is the easiest/best way of doing these kind of changes without affecting existing auto-scale group. May be symlinks to NFS share for php.ini and nginx conf files? if the solution is only symlinks than how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [EC2 User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). You could set up something that downloads a script from S3 and runs it.

> When you launch an instance in Amazon EC2, you have the option of
>   passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common
>   automated configuration tasks and even run scripts after the instance
>   starts. You can pass two types of user data to Amazon EC2: shell
>   scripts and cloud-init directives. You can also pass this data into
>   the launch wizard as plain text, as a file (this is useful for
>   launching instances via the command line tools), or as base64-encoded
>   text (for API calls).
>
> If you are interested in more complex automation scenarios, consider
>   using AWS CloudFormation and AWS OpsWorks. For more information, see
>   the AWS CloudFormation User Guide and the AWS OpsWorks User Guide.

I've tried this out myself, it was really easy - it took me about 20 minutes including creating a few instances for testing and writing it up.

1. Go into IAM and create a new IAM role, or if you already have a role assigned to the EC2 instances edit the current role. Make sure the role allows read only access to S3 - just follow the wizard through. You could use a custom role to allow access to a specific bucket if you like.
2. Create a new launch configuration that does two things:

   - Specifies this IAM role
   - Under advance, have a script in the user data. The script below copies any files and subfolders from an s3 folder to a folder on your new instance. I've provided the script as an image because SF formatting isn't working right. The text version with a few characters missing is below it.

[image: EC2 S3 bootstrapping]

```
/bin/bash  - NB missing #1 at start of line
aws s3 cp  s3://s3-bucketname/foldername/ /ec2-target-folder --recursive
```

You'll have to check into users and permissions yourself as they're different for each setup.

Comment: I am sure that there must be some easy way of doing this....

Comment: This probably is the easy way. Basically, you can run a script on startup, that script copies files from S3 for your Nginx configuration. It's probably about 5 lines, but I haven't done it before so I can't supply those lines. If I get time today I might experiment a little, seems like something I might like to know.

Comment: @Farmi I've tried this out and posted a procedure for you. It's really easy. If you're not familiar with AWS it might take a bit longer just to work out what's going on, but I could probably do screen shots if you get really stuck.